# Time complexity of function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I need to find out the time complexity of the following function using big O notation, however I cannot figure it out. At first I thought it would be O(n^3) because of the three for-loops, however the last 2 of those do not go from 1 to n, where n is the length of the input. Here is the code:

```
def VindSets(kaarten):
    sets = []
    for i in range(len(kaarten)):
        if kaarten[i] == 0:
            continue 
        else:
            kaart1 = kaarten[i]  
            for j in range(i + 1,len(kaarten)): 
                if kaarten[j] == 0:  # Als kaarten[j]==0, dan ligt er op de j-de plek eigenlijk geen kaart. We slaan deze daarom over.
                    continue
                else:
                    kaart2 = kaarten[j]
                    for k in range(j + 1,len(kaarten)): 
                        if kaarten[k] == 0:  
                            continue
                        else:
                            kaart3 = kaarten[k]
                            if IsSet(Kaart(kaart1),Kaart(kaart2),Kaart(kaart3)):
                                sets.append([kaart1, kaart2, kaart3]) # Als de drie kaarten een set vormen, worden ze toegevoegd aan de lijst met gevonden sets.
    return sets
```

Comment: Its Theta(n^3), because (when there's no 0's in the array) the inner loop executes n choose 3 times, which is n(n-1)(n-2)/6. In this case, you're literally choosing every combination of 3 cards from the `kaarten` array.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.combinations)?

Comment: No there is no reason to avoid itertools.combinations(), I just wasn't aware of it when writing this function.